# Encountering 302 Redirect Issue When Frontend Calls Backend APIs Integrated with Okta SAML 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, saml, okta

I'm experiencing a peculiar issue with 302 redirects when making API calls from the frontend to the backend, which is integrated with Okta using SAML 2.0 for authentication. Here's the breakdown of the scenario:

-> Current State:

Okta handles SAML 2.0 authentication with the backend.
When accessing the backend APIs individually via the browser URL bar, I receive the expected API response without any 302 redirects.
However, when the frontend makes similar API requests to the backend, it encounters a 302 status code (redirect) instead of the expected API response.
[image]

-> Observations:

The frontend isn't directly involved in handling SAML assertions; it's a backend-to-Okta setup.

-> Troubleshooting Attempts:

Verified backend configurations for Okta integration.
Reviewed network requests and responses through browser tools, noting no issues when accessing the backend APIs directly.

Why might the 302 redirects occur only when the frontend communicates with the backend APIs integrated with Okta's SAML 2.0, despite successful individual access to the same APIs via the browser?
Any insights or guidance on identifying potential causes or troubleshooting steps to resolve this redirect issue would be highly appreciated.

Backend code for reference

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Value("${registration.id}")
    private String registrationId;
    
    @Value("${entity.id}")
    private String entityId;
    
    @Value("${single.signOn.service.location}")
    private String singleSignOnServiceLocation;
    
    @Autowired
    private RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize ->
            authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).saml2Login()
        // Your SAML 2.0 configuration
        .and()
    // Disable CSRF
    .csrf().disable()
    // Disable CORS
    .cors().disable();

        // add auto-generation of ServiceProvider Metadata
        Converter<HttpServletRequest, RelyingPartyRegistration> relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
        Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    protected RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrations() throws Exception {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("saml-certificate/okta.crt");

        if (!resource.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Certificate file not found");
        }

        try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
            Saml2X509Credential credential = Saml2X509Credential.verification(certificate);

            RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration
                    .withRegistrationId(registrationId)
                    .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party
                            .entityId(entityId)
                            .singleSignOnServiceLocation(singleSignOnServiceLocation)
                            .wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false)
                            .verificationX509Credentials(c -> c.add(credential))
                    ).build();

            return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
        }

    }
    
}
```

Put plainly, the backend is linked up with Okta's SAML 2.0, while the frontend attempts to access the backend's API. However, the frontend's API calls are hitting a roadblock at the 302 stage, preventing them from fetching the API response despite successful authentication. What steps should the frontend take to successfully retrieve the backend's response?

[image]

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I think question need more clarification. I'm guessing you're using SSO SAML profile and as far as I know all SSO profiles require some kind of redirect because user has to end up on identity provider to sign in. So please explain your SAML flow in more details

Comment: The flow typically involves the user attempting to access a protected resource, then being redirected to the Identity Provider's login page to authenticate. Upon successful authentication, the Identity Provider sends back a SAML assertion to the application, which is then validated and used to grant access.

Comment: is there a way to capture session and send it to frontend

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand much from your question. I have no idea what is the current behavior and what do you expect to happen. You sound surprised that there are redirects, but SAML SSO flow can't work properly without redirects. I don't have anything to add until you restructure your question with clear current state and expected bahaviour with some screen shots of the flow from network tab maybe and such.

Comment: @Filip I have made it clear, Put plainly, the backend is linked up with Okta's SAML 2.0, while the frontend attempts to access the backend's API. However, the frontend's API calls are hitting a roadblock at the 302 stage, preventing them from fetching the API response despite successful authentication. What steps should the frontend take to successfully retrieve the backend's response? Do we need to use Sessionid? If yes how

Answer (score 0):

302 is the correct way to respond to the SSO login request by frontend.
Correct flow is

1. Frontend makes a request to SSO login endpoint on backend with username.
2. Based on username, backend retrieves configuration of that user/account to know where to redirect the user.
3. Backend responds with 302 with location being SSO endpoint on idnetity provider, in your case Okta.
4. Frontend redirects user to the URL that was returned by backend.
5. Okta web site is opened and asks user for login if user is not logged in.
6. After user is logged in Okta redirects back to your backend with response.
7. Backend verifies response from Okta and redirects user to the landing page with a new session or error page.

I can't see your URLs, which is fine, so I can't tell what you're receiving as location header. Try to redirect user to that URL, if it's correct, user will continue interaction with Okta and the flow will continue.

Comment: How to do that can we do that in okta or do we need to redirect user from our spring boot application?

Comment: location header is '~/saml2/authenticate/application-name'

Comment: I'm backend developer and I'm not 100% sure how frontend handles redirects, but I'm pretty sure they will be redirected by browser. One thing that is possible is to just return URL from backend and then frontend can manually redirect to that URL. Anyhow, user has to be redirected to the URL generated by backend, using HTTP Redirect or manual redirection

Comment: I also work as a backend developer. When the browser interacts with the backend API, which is secured behind Okta, it initiates calls to '/saml2/authenticate/techshare-saml-preprod', followed by '/login/saml2/sso/techshare-saml-preprod', and finally connects to the backend '/' where my backend controller for the root is:


 `@RequestMapping("/")
 public void redirectToHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String redirectUrl = landingPage;

    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
 }`

Do we make any changes to the backend code?

Comment: Single sign-on URL: http://backend-domain.com/login/saml2/sso/techshare-saml-preprod
Audience URI (SP Entity ID): http://backend-domain.com/saml2/service-provider-metadata/techshare-saml-preprod
Default RelayState: http://frontend-domain.com/#/assets

Comment: There's a situation where the backend is hosted on one domain and the frontend on another, causing issues with the frontend's ability to utilize the backend cookie.